# Less: Quickly Jump to Line Number in Large File

Tags: less

I'm struggling to figure out a way to do this...I'm using `less` to view a large (~1GB) file.  I want to jump to line "$n" in the file - preferably without having to wait for lines 1-($n-1) to scroll by in my terminal.

I would do this in vim using something like this:

`localhost:~# vim myfile +$n`

Is there an equivalent command line option?  If not, is there a way to do this once the file is open in `less`?

Comment: A question that bothered me again and again, when i didn't have the time to search for an answer. Typing 'h' might have helped, for it displays the "SUMMARY OF LESS COMMANDS"...

Answer (score 170, accepted):

If the file is open you can type:

- `100g` to go to the 100th line.
- `50p`  to go to 50% into the file.
- `100P` to go to the line containing 100th byte.

You can use these from terminal by adding `+` in front of them:

```
less +100g bigfile.txt
```

Comment: And don't forget, you can type $ to go to the last line.

Comment: Note that without any suffix it goes to the Nth line `less +100 bigfile.txt`

Comment: can also use `50%` to jump to 50%. More typing but easier to remember, and that also works in `vim`

Comment: Thanks, I knew about `less +G ...` to go to the end of the file. but not the `less +nnng ...`. I have always resorted to using less, but felt concerned sometimes in case I made inadvertent alterations (especially as occasionally these might be production files!)