# "less" (linux) get/go-to X offset in file

Tags: linux, less

I open a big file with this command:
less +G /var/log/blah/file.log

Now when I find the desired info I'd like to know its exact offset in this file, so later I can open that file again and return to that exact place.

So there is the "%X" command which will take me to % inside the file, in offset terms (and not lines!). It's fine, but I'd really love to be able to move to exact, numeric, offset in the file.

**What is the command to get the current offset?**
**And what is the command to move to a specific offset?**

**And if I'm at that already, how do I get the current offset in percent?** (to be used with the "%" command).

Note that I know of marks. They aren't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Got part of my question from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/113039/less-quickly-jump-to-line-number-in-large-file):

**100g** to go to the 100th line
**50p** to go to 50% into the file
**100P** to go to the line containing 100th byte

To determine the current line number or byte offset, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>.

Comment: Found it: Ctrl+g !

Comment: For very large files, you may also want to invoke `less` with `-n` to avoid calculating line numbers.

Comment: The question was about offset (column inside a line) but you gave an answer how go to specific line without actually telling how to go an offset inside the line. So now we have 2 questions at superuser about the same with equal answers :/

Answer (score 0):

With my version the lines currently on screen are displayed at the bottom.

To go to a specific line you can type `<number>G`.

Comment: Since the file is very big (more than GB) I'm not even using lines. I need to deal with offset within the file only. Thanks Rob

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by 'offset' you mean byte-offset (as opposed to characters), you can use the **vi editor** and search for the pattern with

```
/pattern
```

hit Enter. Repeated fwd searching for the same pattern can be repeated with

```
/
```

hit Enter.

Cursor position's line and column numbers are displayed at bottom right, so to go to a particular line, say 201, and column, say 17, you type

```
201G17l
```

That's 201, capital G, 17, lowercase l

If your file consists of only 1 line with your pattern at offset 10125, then open it with vi

```
$ vi my_massive_file
```

and type

```
:goto 10125
```

Comment: i noticed after posting that your file is > 1GB and that is probably why you are using less. `vi` should be able to handle it if you have enough memory

Comment: Yea, it opens way too slow with vi/m. Not good for me. And yes also to your assumption; I mean "offset" as in bytes within the file.